# How can I count all possible subdocument elements for a given top element in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Not sure I am using the right terminology here, but assume following oversimplified JSON structure available in Mongo :

```
{
"_id": 1234,
"labels": {
    "label1": {
        "id": "l1",
        "value": "abc"
    },
    "label3": {
        "id": "l2",
        "value": "def"
    },
    "label5": {
        "id": "l3",
        "value": "ghi"
    },
    "label9": {
        "id": "l4",
        "value": "xyz"
    }
}
}

{
"_id": 5678,
"labels": {
    "label1": {
        "id": "l1",
        "value": "hjk"
    },
    "label5": {
        "id": "l5",
        "value": "def"
    },
    "label10": {
        "id": "l10",
        "value": "ghi"
    },
    "label24": {
        "id": "l24",
        "value": "xyz"
    }
}
}
```

I know my base element name (labels in the example), but I do not know the various sub elements I can have (so in this case the labelx names).

How can I group / count the existing elements (like as if I would be using a wildcard) so I would get some distinct overview like

```
"label1":2
"label3":1
"label5":2
"label9":1 
"label10":1
"label24":1
```

as a result? So far I only found examples where you actually need to know the element names. But I don't know them and want to find some way to get all possible sub element names for a given top element for easy review.

In reality the label names can be pretty wild, I used labelx for readability in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation in 3.4.

Use [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) to transform object to array of key value pairs followed by [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) on key to count occurrences.

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {"$project":{"labels":{"$objectToArray":"$labels"}}},
  {"$unwind":"$labels"},
  {"$group":{"_id":"$labels.k","count":{"$sum":1}}}
])
```